# Can't create bitmap without Color space android

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap, color-space

I wanted to rescale a **bitmap**
I tried a lot of functions to do it and no one worked with me because of color space ,
The error is "can't create bitmap without color spacing"
I used the `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(params...)`
And
`Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap source, int width, int height, Matrix matrix, boolean filter)`
Always same exception , i don't know what to do with it

Comment: paste your code

Comment: Add a colour space. Values without colourspace are meaningless. sRGB is the default colour space of PC and HTML

Comment: see if you add this and pass to createBitmap param, ColorSpace sRgb = ColorSpace.get(ColorSpace.Named.SRGB);

Comment: i need api 29 to use your functionality , and i couldn't find a way to make it available for all devices starting with api 22, i really don't know what to do about it

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error for my custom view when I try to render it in Android Studio. The code however is working fine when run on the device itself.

Unfortunately `ColorSpace` was added in API 26 and therefore I don't see any way of achieving this if the root of your problem is the same - which we don't know by the way.